# What edition of Underworld has Rhona Mitra retconned into it?

Tags: alternate-version, underworld

While watching [**Underworld**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld_(2003_film)) on Netflix, I noticed that in flashbacks the original blonde Sonja ([Jazmin Dammak](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1454251/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t24)) had been replaced by the brunette version from Underworld: Rise of the Lycans ([Rhona Mitra](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0593961/?ref_=nv_sr_1)). Obviously this was done after the release of the third film in order to make Sonja's appearance consistent across the franchise.

However, I own the Unrated Extended Cut on DVD, and it has the original blonde Sonja.

**In what version or edition of the film was Sonja's scenes retconned with the new actress?**

Comment: According to http://forum.blu-ray.com/showthread.php?t=16466&page=5 it may have been a non-disclosed stealth edit, maybe netflix only? Like Lucasing the jedi ghosts in return of the jedi.

Comment: More than likely, the re-re-release when Underworld 5 hits video will have it :P